# Java Thread sleep() assistance

Tags: java, multithreading

Hello the main idea of this is that if the male>female, the female thread has to wait 1000ms(1sec) and then check again. I tried searching for this, but I was unable to find a solution. Could someone please help me?(I've just started learning about threads)

```
public class A implements Runnable {

    public void run(){
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)throws InterruptedException {
        int n = 3;
        int m = 17;
        int f = 13;

        Thread th1 = new Thread(new male(m,n));

        Thread th2 = new Thread(new female(f,n));

        th1.start();
        th2.start();

        //not working
        if (m>f){
                th2.sleep(1000);
        }
        else if(f>m){
                th1.sleep(1000);    
        }
    }

}
```

---

```
class male extends A {

    public male(int male, int count){
        while(male>0){
            male -= count;
            System.out.println("m: " + male);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
class female extends A {

    public female(int female, int count){
        while(female>0){
            female -= count;
            System.out.println("f: " + female);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code will be more readable if you follow these guidelines: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: I do not know why but i see the 'other' image of this question :O

Comment: There are several issues with your code - your local `m` and `f` aren't modified so your main `if (m>f)` statement will always be true in this case, your threads might even finish before you get to these statements, `Thread.sleep()` causes the current executing thread to sleep (not the one you are calling the method on).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Thread.sleep method is a `static` method that puts the current thread "to sleep" for a period.  It cannot be used to put other threads to sleep ... like you are attempting to do.

If you want the child threads to sleep periodically, then the calls to `sleep` need to be made by the respective threads themselves; e.g. in the respective `run()` methods.

For what it is worth ... there is no **safe** way for one thread to cause another thread to sleep or pause.  There is a deprecated API for pausing another thread, but it is has numerous safety and security issues, and should not be used.

---

There's another problem.  The logic you have put into the constructors will be run when you instantiate those classes.  That happens on your main thread when you "new" the `Male` and `Female` objects.  You want that code to run in the child threads ... when they have been started.

Your `Male` and `Female` classes need to implement the `Runnable.run()` method, and that is where the logic of the threads needs to be implemented.

Comment: You should get a compiler warning for calling `sleep` with an instance. If not, check your compiler settings and turn on all warnings.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, instead of having a class A that doesnothing except a main method and implements Runnable and having male and female extend A, consider having male and female Just implement Runnable themselves. Second, your male and female methods contain nothing in their run method, so there is nothing to run on another thread. Therefore, your threads are doing nothing in the first place.

Comment: *be direct subclasses of Runnable* You probably mean "implement", as `Runnable` is an interface, not an abstract class.